# Android socket doesn't write to output

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking

I developed an application which communicates with server over TCP socket connection. When I tested it on emulator, it worked just fine. I could see all intended data flowing through. But when I run the application on my real device, it connects but not writes. To see what's happening, at server side I printed accepted clients and every received bytes. So it says "new client accepted" but never writes any received bytes which means no data received.

My code on Android application, runs without any exception:

```
clientSocket = new Socket(host, port);
PrintStream output = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

clientSocket.getOutputStream().write(new byte[]{67,68,75}); //just some random stuff
clientSocket.getOutputStream().flush(); //neither this ...
output.print("hello");                  //... nor this works
```

At the server side:

```
...

Socket clientSocket = server.accept();
DataStreamInput input = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
System.out.println("New client accepted");

...

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
char ch = (char)input.readByte();
while (ch != '\0') {
     System.out.println("BYTE received: "+ch); //should print sth no matter what, but doesn't
     sb.append(ch);
     ch = (char)client.getInput().readByte();
}

String data = sb.toString().trim();
dataReceived(data);
```

I don't understand why it works with the emulator but not with my device. (Samsung GT-I9500 btw) What could be the problem behind not sending or being unable to send the bytes? Any idea or any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks...

Edit: Something interesting happened. When I print something to output later in a different thread, it sends all of them with previous data.

Comment: if it works with emulator maybe your server is not reachable from the device, what address are you using?

Comment: @lelloman I'm using a virtual server from AmazonAws. 'host' is "ec2-5*********.compute-1.amazonaws.com" and 'port' is "8080"

Comment: Your code is invalid. You aren't sending a null byte, so looping until you read a null byte is futile.

Comment: @EJP Yes in this example it won't quit the while loop because no null byte is sent. But in the loop, there is a System.out.println() that prints every single received byte, it should write something for every iteration even if the loop is not quit, right?